# Валидация имён узлов xml-документа

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml

Имеется возможность добавлять объекты с пользовательским именем (textBox + AddButton) в список. Далее, на основе имен этих объектов будут генерироваться узлы xml-документа. Очевидно, что у названий узлов xml есть ограничения (например, запрет на кириллицу, запрет на имя, которое начинается с цифры и т.д.). Имеется ли способ валидации имени на этапе его ввода в TextBox, т.е. непосредственно до генерирования документа? Или в методе проверки создавать xml-документ и проверять, не выкинет ли он исключение? По-моему, это костыль какой-то =)
Спасибо за внимание

Comment: а если узлы будут всегда одни, но зато будут вводиться пользователем атрибуты, чем вас такой вариант не устраивает?

Comment: Можно написать свой TextBox с ограничением ввода, либо найти готовый.

Comment: @VladimirT, ну атрибуты тоже не могут быть любыми :)

Comment: Возьмите контрол [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/802906/218063) и доработайте, должно быть не слишком сложно.

Comment: зато значения атрибутов могут быть любыми.

Comment: @VladimirT, ну так и значения тегов могут быть любыми. Никакой разницы по сути

Comment: @Андрей NOP, вопрос не в том, как реализовать, просто я думал, может в System.Xml и где-то ещё есть возможность валидации. Я просто не обо всех ограничениях знаю. Думал, может есть готовое решение

Comment: Проверяйте регуляркой

Comment: @Jagailo, буду благодарен за регулярку) Повторюсь: вопрос не в том, КАК реализовать, а в наборе правил. Либо, если есть функция валидации в System.Xml, то ткнуть меня в неё носом)

Comment: @БадаловБадал `[a-zA-Z_]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)`

Comment: @Jagailo, спасибо! Это точно все правила для формирования имён xml-узлов? Не уверен, правда. Всё равно спасибо за вариант

Comment: Ну как сделать валидацию по мере ввода я вам показал, а регулярку можете взять выше (там даже плюсик лишний), либо вот здесь более полные правила: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3158299/6766879

Comment: @АндрейNOP, нет, решение оказалось гораздо проще.. 
XmlConvert.VerifyName(name);
Именно о чём-то подобном я и спрашивал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
{
    XmlConvert.VerifyName(name);
    return true;
}
catch
{
   return false;
}
```

Решение найдено [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936743/efficient-way-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-legal-xml-element-name)
Правда этот метод пропускает кириллицу.. Поскольку xml может содержать кириллицу, в зависимости от кодировки

Запрет на ввод кириллицы:

```
if (new Regex(@"\p{IsCyrillic}+").Matches(nameNewObject).Count > 0)
{
     return false;
}
```

Как правильно заметили в комментариях, логичнее разрешить ввод необходимых символов, нежели запрещать кириллицу.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(nameNewObject, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"))
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Да, но ведь имя элемента xml может содержать и арабскую вязь, и иероглифы...

Comment: То есть вместо запрета на ввод кириллицы следует разрешить только ввод латиницы (а также некоторых символов типа тире, подчеркивания и т. п.)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, именно так и сделал, правда мне достаточно латиницы + цифры.
Дополнил ответ

Comment: Вместо Matches.Count достаточно просто IsMatch, вроде

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо

Comment: Последний вариант, кстати, неверен — наименование тега не может же начинаться с цифры? Должно быть что-то вроде `^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, нет, эта проверка у меня идёт второй, сначала выполняется XmlConvert.VerifyName(name);, который перехватывает наименования, начинающиеся с цифр(и ещё много чего), а уже потом регулярка

Comment: Эээ, в чем тогда смысл? Если строка проходит вторую проверку, то она заведомо пройдет и первую, значит первая не нужна (тем более вариант с выбросом исключения и его перехватом медленный и не красивый)